# Datatables Child Rows Implementation

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables-1.10

Recently, I got a requirement for an implementation of adding Child rows in a table. I have gone through the few APIs and found that datatables fits into my requirement. As of now I am implementing this web application in Springs and getting the data from the controller.
That is $resultSet.
Now this dynamic data I have to render in jsp page. Here I got stucked because I am not able to implement with datatable. I have seen the example of http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html and tried removing Ajax data and used c:foreach loop in place it. But i didn't get any luck.

So can you guys please tell me how do I use datatables with the dyncamic data in order to display child rows.

My main concern is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",  
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
```

How do I represent the above block.
I tried with `<table id="xx"> <c:foreach loop to iterate>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option to feed data into DataTables directly instead of using server-side script to return data via Ajax. This initialization option can be useful when creating a table from a JavaScript data source, or from a custom Ajax data get. However the data has to be of type `Array`.

I'm not familiar with Spring framework but I'm assuming you can produce a string with data in JSON format and output it in your page to assign to `table_data_json`. I'm using a sample JSON string `var table_data_json = '[ /* skipped */ ]';`.

```js
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    var table_data_json = '[{"name":"Tiger Nixon","position":"System Architect","salary":"$320,800","start_date":"2011/04/25","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"5421"},{"name":"Garrett Winters","position":"Accountant","salary":"$170,750","start_date":"2011/07/25","office":"Tokyo","extn":"8422"},{"name":"Ashton Cox","position":"Junior Technical Author","salary":"$86,000","start_date":"2009/01/12","office":"San Francisco","extn":"1562"}]';
  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "data": JSON.parse(table_data_json),
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

If I misunderstood your question, please let me know and I will update my answer.